# Suspend a program when on battery power

Tags: battery, power-management

I’m doing some long-running, CPU-intensive work. This means that I am tethered to a power outlet at all times.

What I’d like to do is ask macOS to suspend a particular program when I’m on battery power and resume it when I plug in.

Googling has failed me. Is there any way? I’m a programmer so I don’t mind going low level if necessary.

Comment: For future readers, the linked answer gave some hints about how to detect battery/power state, but not about how to suspend a program or to detect a power state change without polling. I could not find a way to do either of those. Lucky for me, the program is one that I have written. My solution is to execute `pmset -g batt` every so often and parse the output (ick). If/when I detect that I'm on battery, I sleep in a loop, executing pmset occasionally to see whether we're back on AC adapter power. Ugly, but sufficient.

Comment: ...and you can use SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to pause and resume a process.

Comment: I made github.com/josharian/power/nobatt as a simple utility to solve this. It works only for command line programs, but maybe it’ll be useful for other people in a similar situation.